# Download a .php file without executing

Tags: php, node.js, download, web-development-server

I tried to download a raw php file without executing it in nodejs. but rather i get the html file that gets displayed when the php file is executed.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const file = fs.createWriteStream("test.php");
const request = http.get("http://example.com/php/test.php", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

So is there any way that I can download the `test.php` file intact as a .php file?

Comment: No, there's no way. PHP files are meant to be executed on the server, that's why you'll only get their output when you try to download them.

Comment: You can configure your webserver with php files to not execute them ... but why?

Comment: I was wondering if there were any way. 

Comment: Directly: There is no way. You can, however, use an intermediate script that would output the content of the file you want to download.

Comment: _“I was wondering if there were any way”_ - yes: FTP, or access via the file system. Via HTTP _obviously_ not, otherwise anyone could read passwords or other credentials stored inside PHP scripts, from just any site.

Comment: @04FS seems clear now. Thanks